# How to write integration test that can have multiple truthy results with minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, minitest

How do I test if for something like a redirect, if there there are multiple possible truthy statements in my code that would spit out a redirect?

I tried using redirect with the below. But as you can see, they both technically redirect to same path. It does work, but my test doesn't really tell me if it was truthy because the first case was true or the second case was true.

```
if num == 2
  flash[:notice] = "2 does equal 2"
  redirect_to root_path
elsif num == 3
  flash[:notice] = "3 does equal 3"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Here's what I tried below. See how do I tell WHERE in the code this was successful?

```
  test "check if 2 or 3" do
    post "/root/path", params: { input: 3 }
    assert_redirected_to "/poker/main/"
  end
```

Long story short, my method runs through multiple possible truthy statements, and I need to know WHICH one it was successful on to write my tests.

Any input would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, instead of redirect, I used 'assert_equal', this way I can test for specific notices, which helped me figure out WHERE my test was truthy

```
    assert_equal "full_house. Rank is 4th", flash[:notice]
```